# Yammer impersonation in javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, .net, yammer

I want to post in Yammer using Yammer impersonation in javascript. I can able to do the same in .net SDK.when i try to post using javascript in Yammer impersonation that javascript is not running.Can any one help me with solution. #Yammer

Comment: You are going to have to provide a better description of your problem to get help.